# Python program just stops running?

Tags: python, error-handling

```
while True:
    chunks = []

    for x in range(len(new_match_list)):
        if new_match_list[x] == ID_Input:
            chunks=[new_ID_info_list[x:x+7] for x in range(0, len(new_ID_info_list), 7)]

    if len(chunks) == 0:
        ID_Input = input("Please choose a number from the list provided, and enter it correctly this time!")

    if len(chunks) > 0:
        print (chunks[x])
        break
```

I'm having a problem with my program, where it shows no error but suddenly stops running, pauses for a minute, then stops.

For example, the program stops after producing:

```
Here is the list of complaint IDs you can choose from and ask about : ['1344139', '1344055', '1343332', '1343188', '1343131', '1341190', '1340441', ]
Choose a number from that list, and enter it in. Type in 'Quit' if you want to quit the program: 1344139

.....
```

There is no error message produced whatsoever.

The goal of the code is to print out a list of data, containing 7 pieces of information (such as Zip Code, State) about the specific ID Number.

If the ID Number entered is not in my list of ID numbers (AKA new_match_list), then the "chunks" will remain blank (hence, len(chunks) will be 0), and the user will be forced to re-enter the ID number until it matches the one on my (new_match_list).

If the ID number does match, it should fill out (chunks) and print out the specific part ([x]) of (chunks) related to the ID.

What can I do to fix this error?

**Edit:** I've tried different ways to fix this error, such as substituting:

```
len(chunks) == 0:
```

with

```
if ID_Input not in new_match_list:
```

but nothing has worked. As always the program just stops without giving me an error

Comment: the output you posted would not be produced by the code you posted.  please correct this mismatch.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't name so many variables `x`.  You have one in a for loop, one in a list comprehension (which is inside the for loop), and one in the print statement (which is outside the loop).  I don't even want to think about what this code will actually do.  Clean up the mess and see what happens.  And maybe you can tell us how a program that "suddenly stops running" can pause for a minute and then stop.  How can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I suspect that when control reaches `print (chunks[x])` you want `x` to have the value it had when `new_match_list[x] == ID_Input` was `True`. If so, you need to put a `break` statement as the last line of that `if` block, i.e., after the `chunks=[new_ID_info_list...` line. And, as Paul Cornelius mentioned, you need to change the variable in that list comprehension so that `x` doesn't get clobbered.

However, there's a better way to find the first matching entry in a list: use its [.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method. You will need to put this inside a `try: ... except` block; alternatively, use the `in` operator to test that the ID is in the list before attempting to fetch its index.